# What to put for input type without having it to display as a textbox

Tags: php

does anyone know what to put for input type ="??" where i still want to submit it and all but i do not want it to appear as a textbox as it can be misleading to the user.

```
    <td width="1%"><input type="text"name="admin_id" maxlength="20" size="20" value="<?php echo "$admin_id1"?>" readonly required></td>
```

[image]

Comment: do want to appear = `hidden`?

Comment: I still want to display it, but i do not want it to be displayed in a textbox but still must be inside as i still have to submit it back to the database, basically i do want the background of the word to be white but as grey as seen in the picture

Comment: then use `disabled` or `readonly`

Comment: Make sure you put a space between `input type="text"` and `name="admin_id"`. You can give your text box a class, and then style it with CSS to make it appear greyed out.